# Why doesn't this program compile in VC++2008Express?

Tags: c++, nested-class

This program compiles and runs on TC++ 3.0.

Why don't this program compile in VC++2008Express?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
private:
    class MyNestedClass
    {
    private:
        int myInteger;

    public:
        MyNestedClass(int a)
        {
            myInteger = a;
        }
        void Show()
        {
            cout<<myInteger;
        }
    };
};

int main()
{
    MyClass::MyNestedClass myNestedClassObject(100);

    myNestedClassObject.Show();
}
```

The following messages are shown:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Deleting intermediate and output files for project 'Test', configuration 'Debug|Win32'
1>Compiling...
1>Static_Data_Member.c
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(39) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(39) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(41) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(41) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(41) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(41) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(41) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(41) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(42) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(42) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(42) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(42) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(42) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(42) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(43) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(43) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(43) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(43) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(43) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(43) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(44) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(44) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(44) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(44) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(44) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(44) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(45) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(45) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(45) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(45) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(45) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(45) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(46) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(46) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(46) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(46) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(46) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(46) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(47) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(47) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(47) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(47) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(47) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(47) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(48) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(48) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(48) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(48) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(48) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(48) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(49) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(49) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(49) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(49) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(50) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(50) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(50) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(50) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(51) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(51) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(51) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(51) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(51) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(51) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(52) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(52) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(52) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(52) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(52) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(52) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(53) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(53) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(53) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(53) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(53) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(53) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(54) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(54) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(54) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(54) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(54) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(54) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(55) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(55) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(55) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(55) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(55) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(55) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(56) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(56) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdlib(21) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdlib(21) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdlib(21) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdlib(21) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdlib(21) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdlib(21) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdlib(23) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdlib(23) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdlib(23) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdlib(23) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdlib(23) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdlib(23) : fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
1>Build log was saved at "file://h:\Test\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>Test - 102 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you pointed out what line 39 is...

Comment: possibly because you are compiling as `c` rather than `c++`?

Comment: Note that Turbo C++ 3.0 is 20 years old.  There's going to be a lot of code that it accepts that won't be accepted by modern compilers (and a whole lot more code that modern compilers will accept but Turbo C++ will not).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a C++ program, but you've given your source file a .c extension.

By default, the Visual C++ compiler compiles .c files as C.  Use a .cpp extension or compile with the /TP flag to compile the source as C++.

However, even if you compile the source as C++, the program is still invalid.  `MyNestedClass` is a private member type of `MyClass`, so you cannot construct an instance of it in `main()`.

Comment: +1 very interesting. Does the actual C++ compiler make this assumption or does Visual Studio (which then passes on it's assumption via a compiler option)?

Comment: @JaredPar:  It's a compiler feature.  See also [/Tc, /Tp, /TC, /TP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx)

Comment: @JaredPar You can change it globally in the project's properties if you want to (i.e. always use c++ compiler even for files ending in .c) - at least for the professional version of VS.

Comment: @Voo:  Right; those properties just add the /TP or /TC flag to the arguments given to the compiler.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Oh obviously, I just thought I'd add that he can easily change it without manually adding any compile flags.